# .classList returns undefine in the forEach() loop

Tags: javascript

I created simple collapse and expand mechanism by removing or adding the 'active' class. The removing mechanism works perfectly fine but I have a problem with adding active class on click:

```js
const panelActive = document.querySelector('.panel');
const panelInactive = document.querySelectorAll('.panel:not(.active)');

// console.log(panelInactive);

const collaps = (event) => {
  console.log(event);
  panelActive.classList.remove('active');
};

const expand = (panel) => {
  console.log(panel);
  console.log(panel.classList);
  panel.classList.add('active');
};

panelInactive.forEach((panel) => {
  panel.addEventListener('click', collaps);
  panel.addEventListener('click', expand);
});
```

When the expand function is called, the .classList function returns an undefine value instead of a list of classes:
[image]
So I think thats the reason why it does not work at all.
Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
panel.addEventListener('click', expand);
```

Doesn't pass any explicit arguments to `expand()`.  The default *implicit* argument for an event handler is an `event` object.  (In this case a `PointerEvent`.)  Which you are observing when you do this:

```
console.log(panel);
```

And further observing that the `event` object has no `classList` property when you log this:

```
console.log(panel.classList);
```

The `expand()` function is expecting a "panel" to be provided, but you haven't provided one.  You can do so manually:

```
panel.addEventListener('click', () => expand(panel));
```

---

As an aside, the code is likely to have other problems as well.  For example, the `collaps()` function will only ever "collapse" the "panel" that was originally expanded.  No other panels would be affected.

You can correct this by getting the "active panel" in the function itself, rather than only once when the page loads:

```
const collaps = (event) => {
  console.log(event);
  document.querySelector('.panel').classList.remove('active');
};
```

Comment: also the query that gets the not-active panels looks like it only runs once, and the node lists returned from `.querySelectorAll()` are (I think) *not* live.

Comment: yeap thats the solution

Answer (score 1):

Keep it easy - remove the `active` class from all panels on click, and add it to the clicked one:

```js
const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');

panels.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  panels.forEach(panel => panel.classList.remove('active'));
  event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('active');
}));
```

```css
.panel {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.panel.active {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.panel p {
  display: none;
}

.panel.active p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <h2>One</h2>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <h2>Two</h2>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <h2>Three</h2>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: even better than my poor code :D thx